# EntityNotFoundException while retrieving ManyToOne relation but entity id exists

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7

When I execute query findeAtDate I got the error entityNotFoundException but in database I have the entity with id 4, so could it be some data error in the entity Work with id 4?

[image]

**Work.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_work")
public class Work extends BaseTraceEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[OR]\\d{3}\\/\\d{4}")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 9)
    private String code;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String description;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String address;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "init")
    private LocalDate init;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
    @Column(name = "end")
    private LocalDate end;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "idWorkType", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private WorkType type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCompany", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Order_> orders;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<DeliveryNote> deliveryNotes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Task> tasks;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "work", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<WorkContact> contacts;
...
```

**DeliveryNote.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_deliveryNote")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = DeliveryNote.findAtDate, query = "SELECT dn FROM DeliveryNote dn WHERE :date = :date AND dn.date_d is null")
})
public class DeliveryNote extends BaseTraceEntity {
...
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = WorkAdapter.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idWork", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "deliveryNote2work"))
    private Work work;
...
```

**DeliveryNoteManager.java**

```
@Stateless
public class DeliveryNoteManager {
...
    public List<DeliveryNote> findByAtDate(LocalDate date) {
        List<DeliveryNote> delNotes = this.em.createNamedQuery(DeliveryNote.findAtDate, DeliveryNote.class).
                setParameter("date", date).
                getResultList();

        return delNotes;
    }
...
```

**Work data**

[image]

**DeliveryNote data**

[image]

**Error**

```
23:40:46,607 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-104) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component DeliveryNoteManager for method public java.util.List es.roscam.light.business.work.boundary.DeliveryNoteManager.findByAtDate(java.time.LocalDate): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find es.roscam.light.business.work.entity.Work with id 4
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find es.roscam.light.business.work.entity.Work with id 4
...
```

Comment: Can you share your entity design and the sample data?

Comment: do you need the complete design of deliveryNote as well?

Comment: Where is id field in ypur WorkEntity?

Comment: It is in BaseTraceEntity extends BaseEntity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is an inconsistency between mandatory fields in database and mandatory properties of entity Work.

In database the fields description and address are empty but the entity must receive them as mandatory, so when the manyToOne relation in DeliveryNote with Work try to eager load it produces an error because the fields are empty.

So it receives the error message that some data error in the entity Work with id 4.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution back. I hope everyone could be like you